# Button-position in DIV

Tags: button, css-position

I came back to html&css coding after 10 years or something and quite a lot changed. I feel like Fred Flintstone in Black Mirror universe.

So I have maybe a little stupid question - how to position button in the middle of the div. I mean I text-aligned center in css. But horizontally its still in the top border. Ss below, I just made border of the div in PS to show how its built. Its also responsive so the row with the button go above row with the text when using phone.

[Picture in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PCOH.jpg)

```
  .ghost-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #fffff;
  font-family: Inconsolata, monospace;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 15px; 
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out,
              color 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your HTML structure looks like, but if you can use flexbox check this article out:  https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/ It's pretty great.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet

```
.ghost-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Thanks!